# "Язык Программирования С++". Есть ли перевод 4-ого издания?

Tags: c++, книги

Это издание вышло аж 2 года назад, весь Инет перерыл, а перевода нет. Что за дела? Уже давно хочу купить, да и с возможностями плюсов'11 хочу поподробней ознакомиться. Прошу без ответов наподобие "Учи англесский...", его я знаю, и в крайнем случае на английском книгу и возьму, просто на русском легче читается

Comment: Кто автор книги?

Comment: Нет, нету, где взять понятия не имею, может его еще никто и не перевел.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Bjarne Straustrup, надо думать. Автор, м.б. [это чем-то поможет](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/09/05/cpp_programming_lang_4ed.aspx)?

Comment: @avp А чем "это" поможет? Отобьет желание ее читать?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, черт его знает... Думал там какая-то инфа о планах печати у нас 4-го издания, а оказалось просто обзор ихнего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[На официальном сайте Строуструпа написанно](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html),

> Russian translation in progress

Значит, пока нет.

Comment: Ох, что-то я не заметил этого на сайте. Большое спасибо